# Puma will break breakpoint under dev mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my puma config. The `binding.pry` won't work with puma, I have to remove puma config file to enable the `breakpoint` again

```
    APP_NAME = "SAMPLE"
    app_path = File.expand_path('../', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    pidfile "/tmp/puma.#{APP_NAME}.pid"
    bind "unix:///tmp/puma.#{APP_NAME}.sock"
    stdout_redirect "/tmp/puma.stdout.#{APP_NAME}.log", "/tmp/puma.stderr.#{APP_NAME}.log", true
    workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 4)
    threads 8, 16
    preload_app!

    rackup      DefaultRackup
    port        7617
    rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "development"
    environment rails_env

    activate_control_app
```

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: if you put `binding.pry` at application.rb it will still ignore it under puma server. How could I get rid of that? I want to debug/ breakpoint!

Comment: may be this can help you https://github.com/puma/puma-dev/issues/70